# Erro na inserção dos dados

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Boa tarde Guys,

Estou usando Ajax para enviar dados do meu controller para minha view e me deparei com o seguinte problema.

Tenho essa query:

```
public function get()
{

    $sql = $this->db->select('cliente, programa, proj_principal, informacao, states, codigo')
                    ->from('projetos p')
                    ->join('cliente c', 'p.cliente = c.nome')
                    ->where(' states','1')
                    ->order_by('codigo','ASC')
                    ->get();
    return $sql;
}
```

Que pego os dados da tabela projeto e apenas o codigo do cliente na tabela cliente. Porem quando ela vai pra minha view apenas o primeiro item aparece como ativo...

segue JS:

```
for (j = 0; j < cliente.length; j++) {

                $('#table' + data[i].cliente.replace(/\s/g, '')).append('<tbody><tr><td><p contenteditable="true" id="prog' + cliente[j].id + '">' + cliente[j].programa + '</p></td><td><p contenteditable="true" id="proj' + cliente[j].id + '">' + cliente[j].proj_principal + '</p></td><td class="ml-auto text-center"><p contenteditable="true" id="info' + cliente[j].id + '" >' + cliente[j].informacao + '</p></td>' +
                     '<td><select class="form-control userselect " id="atividades' + cliente[j].id + '">' +
                    '<option value="0">Inativo</option>' +
                    '<option value="1">Ativo</option>' +
                    '</select></td>' +
                    '<td class="ml-auto text-right"><buttom class="btn btn-primary mr-2 botao edit" id="' + cliente[j].id + '"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></buttom><buttom class="btn btn-danger botao remove" id="' + cliente[j].id + '"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></buttom></td></tr></tbody></table>');

               if (cliente[j].states == 0) {
                    $("#atividades" + cliente[j].id).val(0);
                } else {
                    $("#atividades" + cliente[j].id).val(1);
                }
            console.log($("#atividades" + cliente[j].id).val())
}
```

Se caso eu retirar o JOIN, funciona perfeitamente... Porem preciso do Código do cliente.

Alguem da um norte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta maneira, assim funcionará:

```
for (j = 0; j < cliente.length; j++) {

    $('#table' + data[i].cliente.replace(/\s/g, '')).append('<tbody><tr><td><p contenteditable="true" id="prog' + cliente[j].id + '">' + cliente[j].programa + '</p></td><td><p contenteditable="true" id="proj' + cliente[j].id + '">' + cliente[j].proj_principal + '</p></td><td class="ml-auto text-center"><p contenteditable="true" id="info' + cliente[j].id + '" >' + cliente[j].informacao + '</p></td>' +
    '<td><select class="form-control userselect " id="atividades' + cliente[j].id + '">' +
    '<option value="0" '+((cliente[j].state == 0) ? ' selected="selected"' : '')+'>Inativo</option>' +
    '<option value="1" '+((cliente[j].state == 1) ? ' selected="selected"' : '')+'>Ativo</option>' +
    '</select></td>' +
    '<td class="ml-auto text-right"><buttom class="btn btn-primary mr-2 botao edit" id="' + cliente[j].id + '"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></buttom><buttom class="btn btn-danger botao remove" id="' + cliente[j].id + '"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></buttom></td></tr></tbody></table>');

}
```